# Offline distribution of TYPO3 content

Tags: deployment, content-management-system, typo3

I'm currently looking into the possibility of using a CMS as a way of distributing content (user manuals, FAQs, documentation) to offline customers. I tried searching for the possibility of distributing a static offline copy of TYPO3, but was surprised not to find anything so far. There are few custom solutions I have considered (wgeting a static copy, installing a webserver on deployment), but I wonder what would be the easiest way, or whether there already are modules supporting this. We do not have admin rights during setup, thus we can't install any services on the client machine.
I currently do not care whether we use Neos or TYPO3 classic, whichever supports this would be fine.

Thank you for any help that you can give me.

P.S. I'm currently asking somewhat similar but different questions about other CMSes. Adhering to the one objective per question rule, I've felt that using different questions would be the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wget whole page as a static set of HTML pages is fastest sensible solution. Of course there are also other programs which will allow you do to this.

In other case you would need to install some Apache+MySQL+PHP on each client which doesn't make sense.

You can also try [nc_staticfilecache](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/nc_staticfilecache) ext.

Comment: Staticfilecache sounds like exactly what I'm searching for, thank you